# Network bottleneck in Kubernetes from my DNS-provider?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-networking

Let's say I have a Kubernetes setup that consist of the following:

- 3 Control Planes
- 2 Worker Nodes

The two Worker Nodes ensure my apps always can be deployed on more than one machine, and the three Control Planes ensures I always have something that can manage the Worker Nodes - redundancy everywhere.

Now, the bottleneck;
When my DNS-provider forwards `mysite.com` to a machine, it does so to my public IP.
This hits my router, and I need to forward that request to my cluster... but which machine do I forward that to?

I think I am missing something here.
If I have ingress setup, it allows me to take anything that resembles `mysite.com/somepath` and forward it to a load balancer, but how do I get from my router to my ingress?
Don't I need to point the router to the cluster by an IP-address?
And when that node is down, my cluster can't be accessed, right?